# iOS Google OAuth, retrieve friends email adresses

Tags: ios, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I'm trying to get the email addresses of friends of logged in User, from my iOS App using the

```
    [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleListWithUserId:@"me"
                               collection:kGTLPlusCollectionVisible];//kGTLPlusCollectionVisible
```

I have made authentification scopes like described in the Google Docu:

```
    signIn.scopes = @[
                   kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin,
                   kGTLAuthScopePlusMe,
                   kGTLAuthScopePlusUserinfoEmail,
                   kGTLAuthScopePlusUserinfoProfile,
                   @"email",
                   @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read",
                   @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read"
                   ];
```

Result is, I get the list of friends, but WITHOUT the Email address. As I do not get any error message, I'm really stuck, and have no solution

Can someone help?

Thx.

Patrik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email scopes only work for the currently authenticated users profile. They don't enable access to the email addresses for other profiles.

Comment: Then they should change the documentation! There is clearly stated that the GTLPlusPeopleFeed contains the email address when used with www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read see : https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth Are the people from google reading? Can someone help? If it is really so, as Abraham stating, I will mark the answer as correct.

Comment: _the user's Google account email address, as well as any public, verified email addresses in the user's Google+ profile_ refers to the authenticating user.